# ansible - FAILED! => {"msg": "'failed' is not a valid option in debug"}

Tags: ansible, aws-cloudformation, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

In the below code:

```
---
- name: set task definition facts
  set_fact:
    todobackend_task_def_arn:
      "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.TodobackendTaskDefinition | regex_replace('^(.*):[\\d]*$', '\\1') }}"
    todobackend_adhoc_task_def_arn:
      "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.TodobackendAdhocTaskDefinition | regex_replace('^(.*):[\\d]*$', '\\1') }}"

- name: update task definition
  aws_ecs_taskdefinition:
    state: update
    arn: "{{ item }}"
    containers:
      - name: todobackend
        image: "{{ image_tag }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ todobackend_task_def_arn }}"
    - "{{ todobackend_adhoc_task_def_arn }}"
  when: image_tag is defined

- name: run migrations
  aws_ecs_task:
    operation: run
    cluster: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.EcsCluster }}"
    task_definition: "{{ todobackend_adhoc_task_def_arn }}"
    count: 1
    overrides:
      containerOverrides:
        - name: todobackend
          command:
          - "manage.py"
          - "migrate"
          - "--noinput"
  register: migration_task
  when: ('migrate' in ecs_tasks | default([]))

- block:
  - debug: msg= {{ migration_task }}
    when: debug is defined
  - name: "fail if migration task failed"
    fail: msg="One or more migration tasks exited with non-zero exit code"
    with_items: "{{ migration_task.task | default([])}}"
    when: item.containers[0].exitCode != 0
  when: migration_task is defined

- name: run collectstatic
  aws_ecs_task:
    operation: run
    cluster: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.EcsCluster }}"
    task_definition: "{{ todobackend_adhoc_task_def_arn }}"
    count: "{{ instance_count | default(1) }}"
    overrides:
      containerOverrides:
        - name: todobackend
          command:
          - "manage.py"
          - "migrate"
          - "--noinput"
  register: collectstatic_task
  when: ('collectstatic' in ecs_tasks | default([]))

- block:
  - debug: msg= {{ collectstatic_task }}
    when: debug is defined
  - name: "fail if collectstatic task failed"
    fail: msg="One or more collectstatic tasks exited with non-zero exit code"
    with_items: "{{ collectstatic_task.task | default([])}}"
    when: item.containers[0].exitCode != 0
  when: collectstatic_task is defined

- name: configure ecs service
  aws_ecs_service:
    state: update
    name: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.TodobackendService }}"
    cluster: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.EcsCluster }}"
    task_definition: "{{ todobackend_task_def_arn }}"
    desired_count: "{{ instance_count | default(1) }}"
    deployment_config:
      minimumHealthyPercent: 50
      maximumPercent: 200
  register: configure_ecs_service
  when: stack_config is defined

- debug: msg={{ configure_ecs_service }}
  when: configure_ecs_service is defined  and debug is defined

- name: deploy service update
  aws_ecs_service:
    state: update
    name: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.TodobackendService }}"
    cluster: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.EcsCluster }}" 
    task_definition: "{{ todobackend_task_def_arn }}"
  register: update_ecs_service
  when: image_tag is defined

- debug: msg={{ update_ecs_service }}
  when: update_ecs_service is defined and debug is defined
```

---

Below is the error:

```
TASK [set task definition facts] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [update task definition] *****************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:738712609768:task-definition/todobackend-TodobackendTaskDefinition-1Q6N008BB5S3E) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:738712609768:task-definition/todobackend-TodobackendAdhocTaskDefinition-XRWUXMCWSD4A) 

TASK [run migrations] *************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using variables for task params is unsafe, especially if the variables come from an external source like facts. This 
feature will be removed in version 2.6. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'failed' is not a valid option in debug"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/user/git/../todobackend-deploy/site.retry

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1   

$
```

---

for command:

```
$ ansible-playbook site.yml --ask-vault-pass -e '{"ecs_tasks":["migrate","collectstatic"],"stack_config":"true","debug":"true"}'
```

---

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.5.1
```

---

**Edit:**

Below are the changes, after an answer:

**tasks/create_stack.yaml**

```
---
- name: task to create/update stack
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: todobackend
    state: present
    template: templates/stack.yml
    template_format: yaml
    template_parameters:
      VpcId: "{{ vpc_id }}"
      SubnetId: "{{ subnet_id }}"
      KeyPair: "{{ ec2_keypair }}"
      InstanceCount: "{{ instance_count | default(1) }}"
      DbSubnets: "{{ db_subnets | join(',') }}"
      DbAvailabilityZone: "{{ db_availability_zone }}"
      DbUsername: "{{ db_username }}"
      DbPassword: "{{ db_password }}"
    tags:
      Environment: test
  register: cf_stack

- name: Debug output
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ cf_stack }}"
  when: debug is defined
```

---

**tasks/deploy_app.yml**

```
---
- name: set task definition facts
  set_fact:
    todobackend_task_def_arn:
      "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.TodobackendTaskDefinition | regex_replace('^(.*):[\\d]*$', '\\1') }}"
    todobackend_adhoc_task_def_arn:
      "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.TodobackendAdhocTaskDefinition | regex_replace('^(.*):[\\d]*$', '\\1') }}"

- name: update task definition
  aws_ecs_taskdefinition:
    state: update
    arn: "{{ item }}"
    containers:
      - name: todobackend
        image: "{{ image_tag }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ todobackend_task_def_arn }}"
    - "{{ todobackend_adhoc_task_def_arn }}"
  when: image_tag is defined

- name: run migrations
  aws_ecs_task:
    operation: run
    cluster: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.EcsCluster }}"
    task_definition: "{{ todobackend_adhoc_task_def_arn }}"
    count: 1
    overrides:
      containerOverrides:
        - name: todobackend
          command:
          - "manage.py"
          - "migrate"
          - "--noinput"
  register: migration_task
  when: ('migrate' in ecs_tasks | default([]))

- block:
  - name: Debug migration task
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ migration_task }}"
    when: debug is defined
  - name: "fail if migration task failed"
    fail: msg="One or more migration tasks exited with non-zero exit code"
    with_items: "{{ migration_task.task | default([])}}"
    when: item.containers[0].exitCode != 0
  when: migration_task is defined

- name: run collectstatic
  aws_ecs_task:
    operation: run
    cluster: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.EcsCluster }}"
    task_definition: "{{ todobackend_adhoc_task_def_arn }}"
    count: "{{ instance_count | default(1) }}"
    overrides:
      containerOverrides:
        - name: todobackend
          command:
          - "manage.py"
          - "migrate"
          - "--noinput"
  register: collectstatic_task
  when: ('collectstatic' in ecs_tasks | default([]))

- block:
  - name: Debug collect static task
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ collectstatic_task }}"
    when: debug is defined

  - name: "fail if collectstatic task failed"
    fail: msg="One or more collectstatic tasks exited with non-zero exit code"
    with_items: "{{ collectstatic_task.task | default([])}}"
    when: item.containers[0].exitCode != 0
  when: collectstatic_task is defined

- name: configure ecs service
  aws_ecs_service:
    state: update
    name: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.TodobackendService }}"
    cluster: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.EcsCluster }}"
    task_definition: "{{ todobackend_task_def_arn }}"
    desired_count: "{{ instance_count | default(1) }}"
    deployment_config:
      minimumHealthyPercent: 50
      maximumPercent: 200
  register: configure_ecs_service
  when: stack_config is defined

- debug:
    msg: "{{ configure_ecs_service }}"
  when: configure_ecs_service is defined  and debug is defined

- name: deploy service update
  aws_ecs_service:
    state: update
    name: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.TodobackendService }}"
    cluster: "{{ cf_stack.stack_outputs.EcsCluster }}" 
    task_definition: "{{ todobackend_task_def_arn }}"
  register: update_ecs_service
  when: image_tag is defined

- debug:
    msg: "{{ update_ecs_service }}"
  when: update_ecs_service is defined and debug is defined
```

---

How to resolve error: "'failed' is not a valid option in debug"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an interraction between your (very !!!) old ansible version and the mix of old `k=v` + younger yaml syntax in your task. I cannot reproduce this on ansible 2.9.7.

The following syntax should probably fix your issue:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ update_ecs_service }}"
  when: update_ecs_service is defined and debug is defined
```

Note that since your are directly debugging a var value, you can also use:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: update_ecs_service
  when: update_ecs_service is defined and debug is defined
```

Although the above is a good practice, I still strongly suggest you upgrade ansible to a more recent version.

---

Side note: `debug is defined` can usually be replaced with the [`verbosity` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html#parameter-verbosity) to `debug` so you can control the output or not with the `-v` option to `ansible-playbook`.

Comment: I used the first syntax in your answer, I still see the same error

Comment: did you change that in all places where you use the debug module with the same syntax ?

Comment: I have edited my query with the changes you suggested... please check the updated query

Comment: I don't understand what is your edit. There are now new errors in you ansible syntax. Please use yamllint and ansible-lint to verify your files prior to posting. And please upgrade ansible as your original error was not reproducible with a recent version.